# Page not save cookie session in gorilla.sessions

Tags: go, session, cookies, gorilla

I set the session to cookies, but when the page is refreshed my cookies disappear, which is why I cannot use the page in case of successful cookies, I ask you for help and thank you in advance!

```golang
r.HandleFunc("/newroom", newRoomHandler)


func newRoomHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    resultCheckCookie := sessionsTool.CheckAndUpdateSession(r, &w)
    fmt.Println(resultCheckCookie)
    if resultCheckCookie {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "templates/loginForm.html") //Проверка сессии в cookie
    }
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "templates/newPlanningPokerRoom.html")
}

func (s *SessionsTool) CheckAndUpdateSession(r *http.Request, w *http.ResponseWriter) bool {
    s.currentSession, _ = s.sessionStore.Get(r, "session")
    untyped, ok := s.currentSession.Values["UserLogin"]
    if !ok {
        return true
    }
    userLogin, ok := untyped.(string)
    if !ok {
        return true
    }
    fmt.Println(userLogin)
    s.currentSession.Save(r, *w)
    return false
}
```

Comment: `sessions.NewSession` func name is `session`?   please show request and response in chrome network.

Comment: Before login form: 
https://ibb.co/9tVhCC0
https://ibb.co/t2kPXVV
After login in:
https://ibb.co/F6NjzS9
If you go to the page for creating a room again, after login and receiving a session in cookies, the session in cookies disappears and the domain again prompts you to enter your login and password

Comment: Cookies do not magically disappear in browsers: it's either your code resets them, or they expire.

Comment: chrome not found cookies,  print session save err `fmt.Println(s.currentSession.Save(r, *w))`.

Comment: does not output anything, as the interpreter does not pass in the session function function